# what is the easiest way to filter articles in liferay theme

Tags: liferay

Excuse me if I'm asking silly or easy question, but I just can't figure it out.
So, I have a theme, I want to render only portlets, skipping any journal articles.
Which is the most appropriate way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your theme's resources, there is a `portlet.vm` template available in the `_diffs/template` directory. This template allows you to override the default presentation of portlets in general (e.g. change the configuration icons, remove the title bar, ...).

However, inside `portlet.vm` Liferay injects a predefined variable called `$portletDisplay`. This is an instance of the `com.liferay.portal.theme.PortletDisplay` class and represents the portlet that is currently printed.

You can use the `$portletDisplay.portletName` attribute to check for 56, which is the ID for all Web Content Display portlets. So, in short, encapsulate the parent `<div>` inside `portlet.vm` with the following condition:

```
#if($portletDisplay.portletName == '56')
<div class="portlet" ...>
    ...
</div>
#end
```